# Is there an alternative for sys.exit() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

```
try:
 x="blaabla"
 y="nnlfa"   
 if x!=y:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Error!")
except Exception:
    print(Exception)
```

I'm not asking about why it is throwing an error. I know that it raises `exceptions.SystemExit`. I was wondering if there was another way to exit?

Comment: What's wrong with using `sys.exit`? If we don't know why you need a different solution, we can't suggest one that's going to work for you.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, its a legitimate question. If you want to avoid object deletion processing you can use `os._exit`.

Comment: hello @Morgan Thrapp.come on man.thats not working.this is the reason i want an another solution.I've made changes in question.please help me to sort this out.

Comment: I still don't understand what you need. Do you just need to exit your script? If so, what's wrong with `sys.exit`? Do you need to skip the normal exit routine? Then use @tdelaney answer. If it's something else, you need to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some questions like that should really be accompanied by the real intention behind the code. The reason is that some problems should be solved completely differently. In the body of the script, the `return` can be used to quit the script. From another point of view, you can just remember the situation in a variable and implement the wanted behaviour after the `try/except` construct. Or your `except` may test more explicit kind of an exception.

The code below shows one variation with the variable. The variable is assigned a function (the assigned function is not called here). The function is called (via the variable) only after the `try/except`:

```
#!python3

import sys

def do_nothing():
    print('Doing nothing.')

def my_exit():
    print('sys.exit() to be called')
    sys.exit()    

fn = do_nothing     # Notice that it is not called. The function is just
                    # given another name.

try:
    x = "blaabla"
    y = "nnlfa"   
    if x != y:
        fn = my_exit    # Here a different function is given the name fn.
                        # You can directly assign fn = sys.exit; the my_exit
                        # just adds the print to visualize.
    else:
        print("Error!")
except Exception:
    print(Exception)

# Now the function is to be called. Or it is equivalent to calling do_nothing(),
# or it is equivalent to calling my_exit(). 
fn()
```

Answer (score 4):

`os._exit()` will do a low level process exit without `SystemExit` or normal python exit processing.

Comment: Very useful!
Especially when your application catches `SystemExit` exception and you put the `pdb` breakpoint in the loop.