# How do you exit PDB /and/ kill the program?

Tags: python, pdb

How do you kill PDB and the program it's running, similar to LLDB's `proc kill; exit` or `exit (y)` commands?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> isn't working and all the questions I see on here are how to exit while keeping the program running. However, I'm sitting in a PDB session and I found a bug that is causing an endless loop, and while there are indeed other things I can do to kill the program I figured I'd ask what the PDB command is to do it.

Comment: been a while ... "q" isn't it? Google pdb cheat sheet

Comment: I have no idea why the existing `q` answer was deleted. It's the documented tool for the job.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The pdb command to kill the program is `q`, or `quit`. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-quit):

> **q(uit)**
> Quit from the debugger. The program being executed is aborted.

When `q` is not enough to stop the loop (perhaps you have a misbehaving `except` block), you may need to use `os._exit()`, a low-level command which terminates the process immediately. (`q` and `sys.exit` work by throwing exceptions - `bdb.BdbQuit` for `q` and `SystemExit` for `sys.exit`.) `os._exit` will prevent any `finally` blocks or `__exit__` methods from running, so you may have to deal with data corruption or data loss.

Ex: `import os; os._exit(0)`

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511414/2036148)

Or try hitting `Ctrl+\` (kill) in the terminal.

Comment: It's been a year since I asked, but I didn't know about this function and I would imagine it would have worked in that situation. Thanks :)

Comment: `q` is what you're normally supposed to do, though. `os._exit` will prevent things like `finally` blocks and `__exit__` methods from firing.